# Passport control when leaving Geneva airport

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, schengen, geneva

When you travel within a schengen area like from Geneva to Paris, can someone tell me exactly the control I have to go for the departure flights. Is there any passport check? I know that during check in the flying company checks for your identity but I mean other passport control by the airport.

Comment: Geneva might be a poor example because flights to France leave from the French sector, which means they are domestic flights entirely within France. Are you interested in this case specifically or in international Schengen flights?

Comment: At the airport you will need to show your boarding pass and then will pass through swcurity. Depending on your airline you may, or may not need to show and id when boarding. That is it.

Comment: MJeffryes  I have a flight from Geneva to Barcelona but I lost my passport and it is my first time departure from Geneva airport and I dont know if there is any passport control

Comment: @tri What is your citizenship? Do you have a National ID  card?

Comment: What is your nationality and what is the airline?  Different airlines have different documentary requirements for intra-Schengen flights, and the requirements are frequently different depending on whether the traveler is a citizen of an EU or Schengen member state, in which case the requirements may be looser, or of some other country, in which case they may be stricter.

Answer (score 3):

Airports don't have any specific reason to check passports and typically do not do it. In Europe, usually, you will encounter:

- Checks by ground handling personnel contracted out by the airlines. The main purpose is enforcing the airline's price discrimination/yield management operations by preventing ticket resale. They might also have other purposes depending on the destination (ensuring you have documentation to enter your country of destination to avoid fines, checking data that has to be delivered to the authorities…)
- Check by the police/border guards. Everywhere I have been, it's the police (not any private company) who operates border checks and airports have limited influence on that.

Neither of these are strictly mandatory in the Schengen area and I have flown between Stuttgart and Amsterdam without showing any form of ID to anybody. ID checks by ground handling personnel (most often when boarding) are extremely common, even within the Schengen area. Police checks are rarer but cannot be ruled out. Spots checks on arrival or, especially outside Europe, checks when reaching the airport or prior to luggage inspection (e.g. TSA in the US) are also possible.

I am not flying from Geneva very frequently these days but I don't remember undergoing a police check there since Switzerland joined the Schengen area. I once travelled from Geneva with an EU citizen who had lost their national ID and was allowed to fly with only a driving license and insurance card (which did suggest they were a resident in the flight's country of destination but did *not* explicitly document their citizenship).

EasyJet (one of the main operators in Geneva, [accounting for 45% of passenger traffic](http://www.klvinmag.com/en/aeroport-de-geneve-legere-hausse-du-nombre-de-passagers-en-2018/)) definitely checks ID.

Comment: A lot depends on the airline. When flying Swiss or LH I never have had to show an ID at the gate. With Brussels Airlines however always. 
While systematic immigration checks are not done within the Schengen area, currently the French apparently do check all arriving passengers, leading to long queues are BSL, which is why I do not fly there anymore...

Comment: @KristvanBesien It obviously depends on the airline, but not only on that. Regarding immigration checks in France, that's definitely not the case at all airports. It's been ages since I flew to BSL but the website does suggest the French police is checking every non-domestic flight there, I wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

As Relaxed says you can sometimes manage a flight in the Schengen area without anyone ever looking at your ID. I've certainly done this in the past.

More usually however you do run into ID checks somewhere such as for proving you're the person booked on a flight or entering a secure area (such as an airport).

A few years ago I flew from Geneva to Nice, which meant needing to use the French area of Geneva airport. This was a rather odd experience, you go through a gate rather like the ones you go through after security when you disembark a flight- you know the ones, you are now leaving the airport area, no return possible, etc... on the other side of this there was then a security person checking I had a valid ID and ticket to be there.